# java program support multiple languages

Tags: java

how can i make java program working with multiple languages
(frensh, english , arabic .. etc) ,
i mean i wanna make a comboBox ,when i choose one language, all the labels in the GUI interfaces change to the selected language and even the stdin also change to that language.

thanx in advance
Alaa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about `ResourceBundle`s with the GUI interface labels.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html

As for the input changing, it's been asked already:

[Changing Keyboard Input language in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281466/changing-keyboard-input-language-in-java)

Comment: thanx for u phil and for all 
i'll try to make it and i'll let u know ,if i make it successfuly 
thaaanx

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about implementing internationalization which Java fully supports. [This trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/index.html) covers the details of making your application i18n compliant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)s, it loads UI strings on the basis of the locale settings of the application.