# Which java class can be used to print all the languages that java supports?

Tags: java

I want to store all the languages that java support in a table which can be used by application.Do we have any java class to do this?

Comment: by languages you mean english, french etc?

Comment: Java support almost all languages,

you can see [this][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532074/java-program-support-multiple-languages

Answer (score 1):

I think by language you mean locals. try the following

```
import java.util.Locale;

Locale[] localeList = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for(Locale loc : localeList){
        System.out.println(loc.getDisplayName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
Locale[] ls = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

getAvailableLocales() - Returns an array of all installed locales.

Answer (score 0):

If by "language", you mean [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), you can use the following code:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayName());
}
```